# Get text from parent's sibling and change modal title

Tags: jquery

Text of `.modal-title` should be changed to the text of sibling (previous `td`) of clicked button's parent (td).

Now it is edited a little bit. Now I need text from sibling `p` of `td` that has a button.

```js
$(function modalInfo() {

  $('.btn-modal').attr({
    'data-toggle': "modal",
    'data-target': "#exampleModal",
    'style': "border: solid 1px lightgray; border-radius: 20px; background: transparent; padding: 5px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;"
  });
  
});

$('.btn-modal').click(function() {
  var modalTitle = $(this).parent().siblings();
  
  $('modal-title').text(modalTitle);

var modalBody = $(this)
  .closest('td')
  .next()
  .text();

  $('.modal-body').text(modalBody);
});
```

```css
.topic-body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding: 0; width: content; margin:0;">
  <tr class="topic-one">
    <td>Aaa</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
<p class="topic-body">Body text</p>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-one">
    <td>Bbb</td>


<td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-two">
    <td>Ccc</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-two">
    <td>Ddd</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-two">
    <td>Eee</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quos sequi architecto nam dolorem explicabo iure ipsam itaque quia possimus blanditiis temporibus, illum cumque accusamus? Vero tempore sit aliquam velit. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Facere modi nihil quae doloremque, odit omnis? Alias voluptate sapiente odit omnis exercitationem? Porro sapiente, eum quaerat totam explicabo non eos ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam
        ducimus facilis natus ipsam repellendus velit ab accusantium, quas quod ad praesentium earum qui incidunt odit voluptates dolorem temporibus nulla nam!
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's even simpler way, but here is a straightforward one:

```js
$(function modalInfo() {

  $('.btn-modal').attr({
    'data-toggle': "modal",
    'data-target': "#exampleModal",
    'style': "border: solid 1px lightgray; border-radius: 20px; background: transparent; padding: 5px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;"
  });

});

$('.btn-modal').click(function() {
  var modalTitle = $(this)
    .closest('td')
    .prev()
    .text();

  $('.modal-title').text(modalTitle);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding: 0; width: content; margin:0;">
  <tr class="topic-one">
    <td>Aaa</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-one">
    <td>Bbb</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-two">
    <td>Ccc</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-two">
    <td>Ddd</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-two">
    <td>Eee</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-three">
    <td>Fff</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-three">
    <td>Ggg</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="topic-three">
    <td>Hhh</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</table>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus quos sequi architecto nam dolorem explicabo iure ipsam itaque quia possimus blanditiis temporibus, illum cumque accusamus? Vero tempore sit aliquam velit. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Facere modi nihil quae doloremque, odit omnis? Alias voluptate sapiente odit omnis exercitationem? Porro sapiente, eum quaerat totam explicabo non eos ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam
        ducimus facilis natus ipsam repellendus velit ab accusantium, quas quod ad praesentium earum qui incidunt odit voluptates dolorem temporibus nulla nam!
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! Sorry, but why you put here prev after using closest? Please, could you explain in details?

Comment: @Bakhrom Because we want the `prev`ious element of the `closest` TD, which is the parent of the respective buttons. Actually, your initial approach should work too, with a little addition of `.text()`, like: `var modalTitle = $(this).parent().siblings().text();` although that could easily mess things up when you have more TDs as the siblings.

Comment: Now, what is wrong with this? `var modalBody = $(this)
    .closest('td')
    .next()
    .text();

    $('.modal-body').text(modalBody);` `<tr class="topic-two">
                       <td>Aaa</td>
                       <td><button class="btn btn-light btn-modal">Read</button></td>
                       <p class="topic-body">Body</p>
                     </tr>`

Comment: @Bakhrom What does that give you? You didn't add this part on `modalBody` in your original question though. What are you trying to achieve with that? Can you please update the question with this related code.

Comment: @Bakhrom `Now I need text from sibling p of td...` You can't put elements other than TDs on a TR, otherwise your updated code would have worked for the `.modal-body`.

Comment: I got it. I created another td instead of p. And it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is not working if I put here .innerHTML() instead of .text()
Why?